# Asset Liability Management, probabilty of realising the paths in a Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: monte-carlo

An ALM study produces several future real world interest paths, lets say the set consists of 5000 of such paths. What is the chance that one such path becomes reality? If in 50% of the paths the company goes bankrupt can we conclude that the probably of bankruptcy is 50%?

Comment: This chance is $0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't.

In general, these paths are created using assumptions that will not exactly hold in the real world and therefore the outcome of the simulation will never be an exact estimate of the real probability, independent of the number of simulations you use.

However, if the assumptions approximately hold *and* you create a sufficient amount of paths the percentage of paths end up in bankruptcy would hopefully come close to the real probability. At the very least they should give you some idea what the future might bring.